# Find $a$ and $b$ in a 4 equation system

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

$a, b \in\mathbb{R}$. I have four equations:

$$x+3y-2z+t=-3$$
$$3x+11y+az+5t=2$$
$$3x+12y-6z+6t=b$$
$$4x+15y-8z+8t=-5$$

I have to find out the values of $a$ and $b$ where the system is solvable (has exactly 1 solution).

I also have to find out what values of $a$ and $b$ make the system have infinite solutions and no solutions at all (unsolvable). I know I'm asking for a lot of answers, but this is something where I have absolutely no idea how to solve this, I'd really appreciate the help.

Comment: What matrix transformations have you applied so far?

Comment: Do you mean exactly **One Solution Set**?

Comment: @SufyanNaeem yes, that is what I meant

Comment: @Nejc if you contact me on facebook I can give you the wolfram mathematica page with the algebraic explenation

Comment: @JanEerland just did.

Comment: The wrong Jan xD

Comment: @NejcPisk you've to request the one with to (drawed) people and a blue background :)

Comment: Yeah, I've sent you a message, I can't actually add you.

Comment: I dont get anything

Answer (score 0):

I've made a system of equations which gave me this:

1 Solution:

$$t=-\frac{19}{2},y=15,z=\frac{1}{4}(2x+77),b=\frac{309}{2}, a=-6$$

2 Solution:

$$t=\frac{4}{5}-\frac{b}{15}, x=-\frac{9a(b+38)+58b+1434}{45(a+6)}, y=\frac{1}{45}(4b+57),z=\frac{309-2b}{45(a+6)},a+6\ne0$$